# Calculating Joule heating in magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, power

I have problem with calculating [Joule heating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_heating) in alternating magnetic field perpendicular through circulate plate with radios a and height h. Lets say that alternating magnetic field is in form of this equation $\mathbf B=\mathbf B_0\cos(\omega t)$, so I guess  by  Maxwell-Faraday equation you can get out E field (because of eddy currents):

$$\oint_l\mathbf E\cdot d\mathbf l=-\int_a\frac{\partial\mathbf B}{\partial t}\cdot d\mathbf A$$

So I inserted here for circle and I get out this:
$$
2\pi r\cdot\mathbf E=-\pi r^2\cdot\frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t} \\
2\pi r\cdot\mathbf E=-\pi r^2\cdot\omega\mathbf B_0\sin(\omega t) \\
\mathbf E=\frac r2\omega\cdot\mathbf B_0\sin(\omega t)
$$

I take Joule heating equation 
$$
P=\mathbf J\cdot\mathbf E
$$
and united with this equation, $\mathbf J=\sigma\mathbf E$,
and get this
$$
P=\sigma\frac{r^2}{4}\omega^2B^2\sin^2(\omega t)
$$

and I said $\sin^2(\omega t)=\frac12$ so that to get rid of $\sin(\omega t)$ and get this:
$$
P=\sigma\frac{r^2}{8}\omega^2B_0^2
$$

The total power I get by integrating over the volume of plate:
$$
P_d=\frac{\sigma}{8}\omega^2B_0^2\int_0^ar^2\cdot2\pi\cdot h\cdot rdr \\
P_d = \frac{1}{16}\sigma\pi ha^4B_0^2\omega^2
$$
But the right solution to this is 
$$
P_d = \frac{1}{16}\gamma\pi ha^4B_0^2\omega
$$

First I think my volume is wrong and how do you get rid of $\omega^2$ and how can I get $\gamma$. Can someone please help me with this?